# How can I plot my lmer() mixed model growth curves in r?

Tags: r

I have constructed a mixed effect model using lmer() with the aim of comparing the growth in reading scores for four different groups of children as they age. 
I would like to plot a graph of the 4 different slopes with confidence intervals in R in order to visualize this relationship but I keep getting stuck.

I have tried to use the plot function and some versions of the ggplot as I have done for previous lm() models but it isn't working so far. Here is my attempted model which I hope looks at how the change in reading scores over time(age) interacts with a child's SESDLD grouping (this indicated whether a child has a language problem and whether or not they are high or low income).

```
AgeSES.model  <- lmer(ReadingMeasure ~ Age.c*SESDLD1 + (1|childid), data = reshapedomit, REML = FALSE)
```

The ReadingMeasure is a continuous score, age.c is centered age measured in months. SESDLD1 is a categorical measure which has 4 levels. I would expect four positive slopes of ReadingMeasure growth with different intercepts and probably differing slopes.

I would really appreciate any pointers on how to do this!

Thank you so much!!

[The type of plot I would like to achieve - this was done in Stata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7Dei.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You mention that you've tried several things already, could you share the code to let us see what it is that you've tried? Could you also share (a sample of) the data you are using?

Comment: I most often approach this sort of problem by getting the predictions from the model and then plotting.  I wrote a [post](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/11/16/plot-fitted-lines/) about this where I include an [example from a mixed model fit with `lme()`](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/11/16/plot-fitted-lines/#plotting-fitted-lines-from-an-lme-object).  Working with lme4 would be fairly similar; the main difference is in `predict.merMod()` vs `predict.lme()`.